# Open documents in tabs in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to open documents in tabs in Microsoft Word, in the same manner as tabbed browsing in browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](http://www.pcworld.com/article/244837/add_document_tabs_to_word_excel_and_powerpoint.html) will do it, it's called [Office Tabs](http://office-tabs.com/index.htm).  Though, I have read there are some crashes during certain feature uses.

Hope that helps.